# What does "Eat this!" mean in Gurenn Lagann?

Tags: gurren-lagann

In the final battle of Gurren Lagann, during the famous "My drill is the drill that will pierce the heavens" scene, Simon upgrades his drill into an extra large drill. He raises the big drill over his head and shouts "Eat this!" and then uses it to attack. The baddie does not like this and shouts "Never!". Then [they fight.](https://www.youtube.com/embed/P5nLYX5a2Io?start=29)

I wonder what is the Japanese version of that line? I presume the English was chosen to match the tone rather than the literal meaning. What is the literal translation of the Japanese back into English? Is this a common thing to say in anime before doing a sicknasty and also super cool finisher move?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Surprisingly, the translation is accurate in both a literal and figurative sense. His line is 「くらえ」 or "kurae", which literally translates to "Eat it!", and is also used to mean "Take that!" when you strike at someone. It derives from 食らう (or its variant 喰らう), a verb meaning "to eat", although if you're studying Japanese you'll usually encounter 食べる (taberu) first.